# Expressjs mounting api on different route "Cannot read property 'handle' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, express

What I am trying to achieve is my statics being loaded on `/` , with the api mounted at `/api`

Here is my main file:

```
var express = require('express');
var server = express();
var app = require('./api/app');

server.use(express.static('/', __dirname + '/public'));
server.use('/api', app(server));

server.listen(3000);
```

My app.js file:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
        app.get('/users/:id', function(req, res, next){
            res.json(req.params);
        });
    }
```

I am getting a `Cannot read property 'handle' of undefined` error. I still haven't quite got my head around express' `use` and i'm sure im making a very novice mistake but just not sure how I can configure to get the result I would like.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Router instead with Express 4.x:

```
// main.js
var express = require('express');
var server = express();
var api = require('./api/app');

server.use(express.static('/', __dirname + '/public'));
server.use('/api', api());

server.listen(3000);


// ./api/app.js
var router = require('express').Router();
module.exports = function() {
  router.get('/users/:id', function(req, res, next){
    res.json(req.params);
  });
  return router;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`use` expects to receive a middleware function, but in this example it's not actually getting anything (notice that there's no `return` value in app.js). One way to fix this would be to return an instance of express' [Router](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router) middleware:

```
var express = require('express');

module.exports = function(app) {
  var apiRouter = express.Router();
  apiRouter.get('/users/:id', function(req, res, next){
    res.json(req.params);
  });

  return apiRouter;
};
```